# Ideal way of storing Original Image, Thumbnail Image names in database

Tags: php, database, file, filenames, database-schema

I would like to know the best way to store the image names (original/thumbnail) in the database. I want to rename **original.jpg** as **timestamp.jpg** and thumbnail as **timestamp_thumb.jpg**.

Is it good to store the **timestamp.jpg** and **timestamp_thumb.jpg** image names in 2 separate columns in the database or just storing **timestamp.jpg** is fine wherein I can append _thumb in the programming logic when I need the thumbnail.

Any suggestion other than the one I have in mind is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure (with 100% certainty) that the name of the thumbnail will always be found by appending _thumb at the end and that there will never be more than a single thumbnail then yes, you don't have to store this information in the database as this is simply a duplicate piece of data.

If this rule change in the future for whatever raison, you will always have the possibility of adding a new column to the database and change the code; however, this will require some working times and $$$ for making the update.

However, you will learn with more experience that the rules that are supposed to never, never change will often do so and not only they will do so but often, they will do it a in a much shorter time frame that you would have tought possible.

It's up to you to evaluate all this and come with what you think will be the best solution in your case but personally, I prefer to try to never paint myself in a corner and therefore, I usually choose the solution that I think will be the one the most flexible in the future; even if this must come with a price such as a greater memory consumption.

Comment: chances of changing the paths or names is very less. so, how do you conclude in this case?

Comment: Depends on your needs.  Often, the main repertory will remain the same but sub-directory will be added.  If the sub-repertory follow a rule (like to be the first letter of each image's name) then it can be easily coded at the client level; if not, you can add the sub-repertory either in its own column or directly in the same column as the image's name.  Like for everything else, it's your choice to make.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing these images in the database I would recommend storing them in a directory. Depending on the nature of these images it may be best to store them in separate directories as well. Then you can just store the path of the image in the database and use it accordingly.

Comment: Is it good to store both the original and thumbnail paths including the filenames in the database?